# How to watch file changes developing in NestJs app inside Docker container

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm having a problem with **NestJS** and **Docker**. I want to run the development script via npm start: dev but the problem is that the app runs ok but it dosn't detect any change in the souce files, so I cant use it to develop my app.

This is part of my **docker-compose.yml**:

```
messages:
   image: c2c/messages:v1
   command: npm run start:dev
   build:
     context: ./services/c2c-server-messages
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
   container_name: c2c_server_messages
   depends_on:
     - postgres
     - nginx
   networks:
     c2c_net:
       ipv4_address: 172.28.1.5
```

And the **Dockerfile** of my Nest app:

```
FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /api/messages
ADD . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

My npm start:dev script in **package.json**:

```
"start:dev": "tsc-watch -p tsconfig.build.json --onSuccess \"node dist/main.js\"",
```

The **console output** show me this, but the app dosn't detect the file changes:

```
c2c_server_messages | 7:26:29 PM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
c2c_server_messages | [Nest] 36   - 07/31/2019, 7:26 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
c2c_server_messages | [Nest] 36   - 07/31/2019, 7:26 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +63ms
c2c_server_messages | [Nest] 36   - 07/31/2019, 7:26 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +2ms
c2c_server_messages | [Nest] 36   - 07/31/2019, 7:26 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmCoreModule dependencies initialized +151ms
c2c_server_messages | [Nest] 36   - 07/31/2019, 7:26 PM   [InstanceLoader] TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized +1ms
c2c_server_messages | [Nest] 36   - 07/31/2019, 7:26 PM   [InstanceLoader] MessageModule dependencies initialized +2ms
c2c_server_messages | [Nest] 36   - 07/31/2019, 7:26 PM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {/}: +8ms
c2c_server_messages | [Nest] 36   - 07/31/2019, 7:26 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, GET} route +6ms
c2c_server_messages | [Nest] 36   - 07/31/2019, 7:26 PM   [RoutesResolver] MessageController {/messages}: +1ms
c2c_server_messages | [Nest] 36   - 07/31/2019, 7:26 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/, POST} route +2ms
c2c_server_messages | [Nest] 36   - 07/31/2019, 7:26 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/all, GET} route +2ms
c2c_server_messages | [Nest] 36   - 07/31/2019, 7:26 PM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +5ms
```

Comment: What benefits are you hoping to get from using Docker here, as opposed to a local Node installation?

Comment: Hello @DavidMaze the benefit is to make use of the other services initiated by docker-compose.

Answer (score 10):

I have it working now :)

The key is to create a **volume** in docker-compose with the local machine root folder of your microservice folder, in this case **./services/c2c-server-messages** as the root of the app in the container **:/api/messages**

In this way, you are using your local files to run the app and not the files copied to the container, so you can watch for the changes when you save a file.

Example:

```
  messages:
   image: c2c/messages:v1
   volumes:
    - ./services/c2c-server-messages:/api/messages
   command: npm run start:dev
   build:
     context: ./services/c2c-server-messages
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
   container_name: c2c_server_messages
   depends_on:
     - postgres
     - nginx
   networks:
     c2c_net:
       ipv4_address: 172.28.1.5
```

Answer (score 3):

I spended 5h to find this https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/common-errors#file-change-detected-loops-endlessly.

I had similar problem and solved it by adding `"watchOptions": { "watchFile": "fixedPollingInterval" }` to tsconfig.

Comment: Hi Olbert. Thanks for your time and contribution. The whole point of the question is developing app inside Docker and mounting the source code directory to the docker instead of copying it by the `ADD` command.

Comment: I mounted code as the volume and didn't use ADD or COPY command for it. The problem was about how ts watching file changes. Changing configuration solved my case, maybe would be helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a new option to achieve this. There is now a

```
docker compose watch
```

that would allow you to sync the file into your service container.

actions available are

- sync
- rebuild
- sync+restart

sample docker compose file :

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: npm start
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync
          path: ./web
          target: /src/web
          ignore:
            - node_modules/
        - action: rebuild
          path: package.json
```

more details can be found https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/

Answer (score 0):

When you run `docker-compose ...`, it looks for a matching image (`c2c/messages:v1`) and if it...

- finds the image locally, it runs it
- doesn't find it, your `docker-compose.yaml` will cause docker-compose to build  the image.

Once running, one way to change the running process, is to change the files *within* the container image and then trigger to process to reload them. But, it is considered good practice to have 'immutable' (don't change) containers.

One way you may address this is to:

- add your sources to source control
- use some unique identifier of your source to detect changes.

(commonly a hash of your sources e.g. with git `git --rev-parse HEAD`)

If your sources change, the hash will change and you can use this to trigger a rebuild of the image *when* docker-compose next starts. A simple way to do this would to be to:

- `TAG=$(git rev-parse HEAD)`
- then use the hash as the tag for your image (instead of `v1`), e.g. `c2c/messages:${TAG}`

Your workflow would become:

- change your sources
- calculate the hash
- `docker-compose up...` referencing the image tagged with the hash to force rebuild

Using source control gives you a history of your sources.

Using image tags of your source's hashes allows you to match images to commits

Comment: I want to rebuild the image every time my source code changes in development, I can't commit every time. Is this possible?

Comment: You should probably script the flow... `docker-compose down`, rebuild your image and tag it appropriately, edit your docker-compose.yaml, `docker-compose up`. It's possible to volume mount the sources into the image too and then you'd need only restart the container|process for them to be detected but then the merits of using docker are less clear.